# I am trying to run below code in appium on wifi. ( Original error: Could not find a connected Android device.)

Tags: selenium, adb, appium-android

Below Code is for Launching application in appium but i am unable to launch application remotly using wifi. But when i check adb device it was connected to mobile phone. After running script it cant get connected device in adb..it will kill server

```
 public class TestLauncher 
              { 
     public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException 

  {

     AppiumDriver driver;
     DesiredCapabilities capabilities=new DesiredCapabilities();

     capabilities.setCapability("noReset","true");
       capabilities.setCapability("fullReset","false");
       capabilities.setCapability("udid","192.168.1.163:5555");
       capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","SWIPE ELITE");
       capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
       capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion","5.0.2");
       capabilities.setCapability("browserName","");

       File file = new File("/home/nishant/APK/SoftController","com.x18thparallel.softcontroller-msg_support_wo_ime_change-vA.3.219.apk");
       capabilities.setCapability("app",file.getAbsolutePath());

       driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not much to say without appium server logs, but lets start with simple: use correct capabilities for Android:

```
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities= new DesiredCapabilities();
 capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");     
 capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","SWIPE ELITE");
 capabilities.setCapability("appWaitPackage","your_app_package_name");     
 capabilities.setCapability("appWaitActivity","activity_name_to_wait");
 File file = new File("/home/nishant/APK/SoftController",
   "com.x18thparallel.softcontroller-msg_support_wo_ime_changevA.3.219.apk");
 capabilities.setCapability("app",file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Check official appium server [documentation](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md) to understand capabilities